# Redis Stack Exchange how to delete or get keys by pattern

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I installed Stack Exchange redis client in C#.
I can only delete one key or array of keys but I don't know how to delete keys with prefix.
Or another solution can be first get all keys by pattern and then delete them. But I don't know how to get keys  by pattern too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Deletion is separate by key, unless you are flushing the entire database.

Key scanning is readily available on the `IServer` API, and is discussed much more here: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan

However, it should still usually be avoided in production - that isn't the intended use-case for redis.

Comment: Your documentation link is dead.

Comment: @ErroneousFatality fixed, ta

Answer (score 34):

You can do as the following to batch delete items from redis cache. (StackExchange.Redis.StrongName v1.0.488)

```
foreach (var ep in _muxer.GetEndPoints())
{
    var server = _muxer.GetServer(ep);
    var keys = server.Keys(database: _redisDatabase, pattern: pattern + "*").ToArray();
    _db.KeyDeleteAsync(keys);
}
```

`_muxer` is instance of `ConnectionMultiplexer`

It does not delete by pattern as you asked but much faster than deleting each key separately.

Comment: How does this work in a cluster? We are getting twice as many endpoints (including the slaves) and deleting too many keys, should we filter for server.IsSlave == false ?

Comment: Haven't tried it but I think you should invoke the same servers which used in single delete methods.

Comment: Also reader should consider that there may be another databases if using cluster(_redisDatabase default is 0)

Comment: It works. One thing to add I had a problem slowing me with direct connections to master/slave nodes. For me helped disabling vpn on local machine or running the code on prod machines. IP addresses could not be resolved for some reason.

Comment: What's the DI for `_muxer`?  I am using `services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache` and tried DIing `ConnectionMultiplexer`, but it comes back as null.

Comment: I've been using this approach for old .net and am not sure how it's registered in .netcore. This may help maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272957/what-are-the-key-difference-in-using-redis-cache-via-connectionmultiplexer-and-a

Comment: How do you get the _db ? ToArray() also doesn't seem to exist on the current version of the driver.

Comment: the database comes from the connection so presumably you can: `_db = _muxer.GetDatabase();` you can read through how it's done in the MS wrapper: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis/RedisCache.cs and it's mentioned in the docs: 
https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics