# Scan Cache key in Redis Cache Using C#

Tags: c#, caching, redis, invalidation, stackexchange.redis

I am using Redis Cache in my project. Now there is a situation that cache is dynamically generate like "KeyPrefix"+i   i is a dynamic value

Now I want to delete all keys that having prefix "KeyPrefix"

How it posible as in my code I can delete only matching key. But I need to delete all keys that containing some prefix.

```
  IDatabase cache = RedisDistributedCacheManager.GetDatabase();
                cache.KeyDelete(cacheKey);
```

Thanks
Dalvir

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redis Stack Exchange how to delete or get keys by pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488830/redis-stack-exchange-how-to-delete-or-get-keys-by-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Redis key scan targets a server, not a single database. So you may get the server variable and then use the `Keys` method to get all needed keys:

```
var server = conn.GetServer(someServer);    
server.Keys(pattern: "*foo*"))
```

Check the doc first:
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/KeysScan.md